# Convert an array of numeric byte values into a string with jq

Tags: json, utf-8, binary, jq, implode

I have the binary representation of an UTF-8 string as an array of numeric values, each in the range of 0..255.

How to convert that array into the string using `jq`? The built-in `implode` deals with the codepoint arrays only. Besides, there's no functions for bitwise operations in `jq`.

---

Such arrays are observed as values in the newman's (Postman CLI) json output, property `response.stream.data`.

For instance, the string "Hi, Мир!" goes into `[72,105,44,32,208,156,208,184,209,128,33]` byte array, while its codepoints are `[72,105,44,32,1052,1080,1088,33]`. `implode` of the latter gives the original string, while `implode` of the former gives "Hi,ÐÐ¸Ñ!" or something like that.

Comment: I don't know of any builtins or other external tools that could be utilized here but we should be able to write a function to convert the byte array to its corresponding codepoints all in jq.

Comment: Agreed. The absence of bitwise operations is not a problem -- we can use integer arithmetic instead. But (for the simplest case of codepoints < 2048) I don't know how to pair the sequence of bytes and to select elements based on the previous element's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another approach using `foreach`. The main idea is to keep the number of bytes left to read (`.[0]`) for the current char and the bits read so far (`.[1]`). Here is the filter:

```
[foreach .[] as $item (
    [0, 0]
    ;
    if .[0] > 0 then [.[0] - 1, .[1] * 64 + ($item % 64)]
    elif $item >= 240 then [3, $item % 8]
    elif $item >= 224 then [2, $item % 16]
    elif $item >= 192 then [1, $item % 32]
    elif $item < 128 then [0, $item]
    else error("Malformed UTF-8 bytes")
    end
    ;
    if .[0] == 0 then .[1] else empty end
)] | implode
```

Also, errors detection for malformed bytes is not complete.

Answer (score 3):

```
def btostring:
  if length == 0 then ""

  elif .[0] >= 240 then
     ([((((.[0] - 240) * 64) + (.[1] - 128)) * 64 + (.[2] - 128)) * 64 + (.[3] - 128)]
      | implode) + (.[4:] | btostring)

  elif .[0] >= 224 then
     ([  ((.[0] - 224) * 64 +  (.[1] - 128)) * 64 + (.[2] - 128)]
      | implode) + (.[3:] | btostring)

  elif .[0] >= 128 then
     ([  (.[0] - 192)  * 64 +  (.[1] - 128) ]
      | implode) + (.[2:] | btostring)

  else  (.[0:1] | implode ) + (.[1:] | btostring)
  end;
```

#### Example:

```
def hi: [72,105,44,32,208,156,208,184,209,128,33] ;

hi | btostring
```

Output (using `jq -r`):

```
Hi, Мир!
```

#### Extended example:

```
def hi: [72,105,44,32,208,156,208,184,209,128,33];
def euro: [226,130,172];        # 11100010 10000010 10101100
def fire: [240,159,156,130];    # 11110000 10011111 10011100 10000010

(hi, euro, fire) | btostring
```

Output:

```
Hi, Мир!
€
```

(On some devices, the last line above will be a box rather than a triangle.)

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Just discovered 'foreach' and developed another variant with it.

Comment: Won't that tail recursion slow down the conversion for a long string? There might be responses up to several megabytes.

Comment: Thank you. Also, it seems that there is some error in the latest jq on Windows x64. The results of your approach and mine differ starting with the byte at offset 65536, the former gives messed output. The input given is slightly over half a megabyte.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the version of jq that's causing problems (e.g. jq --version)?  Have your tried a non-windows jq? Would it be possible to share (e.g. via gist) the array of integers that illustrates the problem?

Comment: jq-1.5 on Windows 10 x64, downloaded from https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.5/jq-win64.exe. I can't share the original input, but here is another example (the list of some authors of OEIS articles): https://gist.github.com/tsvx/0b193cc0a2e01e2b4e57486d33888362
I have tried non-native-windows jq (MSYS2 and WSL), but failed due to some invocation problems.

Comment: Could you please try a recent version for windows - see https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Installation#windows-using-appveyor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163848/discussion-between-tsul-and-peak).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a non-recursive version of the recursive `btostring` given elsewhere on this page, mainly to illustrate how in jq a recursive implementation can be transmogrified into a non-recursive one.

```
def btostring:
  . as $in
  | [ foreach range(0;length) as $ix ({skip:0, point:[]};
        if .skip > 0 then .skip += -1
        elif $in[$ix] >= 240 then
          .point = [(((($in[$ix]   - 240)  * 64)
                     + ($in[$ix+1] - 128)) * 64
                     + ($in[$ix+2] - 128)) * 64
                     + ($in[$ix+3] - 128)]
          | .skip = 3
        elif $in[$ix] >= 224 then
          .point = [  (($in[$ix]   - 224)  * 64
                     + ($in[$ix+1] - 128)) * 64
                     + ($in[$ix+2] - 128)]
          | .skip = 2
        elif $in[$ix] >= 128 then
          .point = [   ($in[$ix]   - 192)  * 64
                     + ($in[$ix+1] - 128)]
          | .skip = 1
        else .point = $in[$ix:$ix+1]
        end;
        if .skip == 0 then .point|implode else empty end) ]
  | add ;
```

Comment: Nice alternative. I've fixed the compile error in your last edit. Just compared this with the recursive alternative above on my system journald data. It's just as fast, there's no difference. 17,000 log entries take 2 seconds to be formatted. So the recursion is not a performance issue. I'd opt for its shorter code.

Comment: @ygoe - Thanks for fixing the typo.  Recent versions of jq optimize some forms of tail-recursion (TCO), as seems to be the case here.

Comment: I made an [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63711319/143684) to this that silently ignores invalid UTF-8. I needed this because Journal can have such data and my log processor just stopped there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [answer of peak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48431009) that I used successully, here's an extension that does not break or fail with invalid [UTF-8 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Invalid UTF-8 start bytes (128-193, 245-255) or sequences are interpreted as ISO 8859-1.

```
def btostring:
    if type != "array" then .
    elif length == 0 then ""
    elif .[0] >= 245 then
        (.[0:1] | implode ) + (.[1:] | btostring)
    elif .[0] >= 240 then
        if length >= 4 and .[1] >= 128 and .[2] >= 128 and .[3] >= 128 then
            ([((((.[0] - 240) * 64) + (.[1] - 128)) * 64 + (.[2] - 128)) * 64 + (.[3] - 128)] | implode) + (.[4:] | btostring)
        else
            (.[0:1] | implode ) + (.[1:] | btostring)
        end
    elif .[0] >= 224 then
        if length >= 3 and .[1] >= 128 and .[2] >= 128 then
            ([  ((.[0] - 224) * 64  + (.[1] - 128)) * 64 + (.[2] - 128)] | implode) + (.[3:] | btostring)
        else
            (.[0:1] | implode ) + (.[1:] | btostring)
        end
    elif .[0] >= 194 then
        if length >= 2 and .[1] >= 128 then
            ([   (.[0] - 192) * 64  + (.[1] - 128) ] | implode) + (.[2:] | btostring)
        else
            (.[0:1] | implode ) + (.[1:] | btostring)
        end
    else
        (.[0:1] | implode ) + (.[1:] | btostring)
    end;
```